# performSegue from CollectionViewCell didSelectItemAt inside a navigation- and tabbarcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uicollectionviewcell

I am going crazy as I can only get the modal popover working. My goal is to keep the destinationVC in both the navigation AND the tabbarcontroller.

As you can see from all my commented code, I have tried quite a lot. Some of code crash the app, others don't make an impact at all when I click the cell.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let Storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let DestinationViewController : PlayEpisodeViewController = Storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PlayEpisodeViewController") as! PlayEpisodeViewController

    DestinationViewController.getEpisodeName = episodesArray[indexPath.row].EpisodeName
    DestinationViewController.getEpisodeFileURL = episodesArray[indexPath.row].EpisodeURL
    DestinationViewController.getEpisodeImage = episodesArray[indexPath.row].EpisodeImage

    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: DestinationViewController)
    //UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.show(navController, sender: Any?.self)
    //.pushViewController(DestinationViewController, animated: true)
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    //performSegue(withIdentifier: "playEpisodeSegue", sender: self)
    //shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier: String, sender: self)
    //show(navigationController, sender: Any?.self)
    //present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)        
}
```

Comment: If the tab bar controller selected view controller has a nav controller attached this would work: ```self.navigationController?.pushViewController(DestinationViewController, animated: true)```

Comment: That was my first thought as well, but I get:
Value of type 'EpisodesRow' has no member 'navigationController'

EpisodesRow being my class inside my viewcontroller. That is why is used the long string to go back to my rootviewcontroller.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to keep single responsibility principle, and incapsulate as much as possible inside you class. (i.e. avoid using UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController? etc.)
2. The easiest way to organise it using storyboard: 
   select you collection view controller, embed it into navigation controller, embed it into tab bar (or perhaps add "ViewControllers" Segue from tab bar controller to navigation controller)

[image: Like this!]

Comment: Hi Michael,

I have this, which seems similar to what you have?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/48utjfzy2ykymjn/tabbar-navcontroller.png?dl=0